# NPM Issues after installing NPM in angular project

Tags: angular

When I start NPM this error appears After I installed NPM in Asp.net Core and angular project
Script file src/assets/freeze-ui/freeze-ui.js does not exist

Comment: add more information to your issue, such as the dependencies, the error.

Answer (score 0):

normally npm modules is installed in **node_modules/freeze-ui/freeze-ui.js**. You may want to change it's pathing and try importing it.

Check your **package.json** to see if the said module is there as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).